# Subtracting 2 timestamps based on a 24 hour time clock?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, data-science

I have a df that looks like

```
         Date               Time 
2019-07-23 21:17:47.599  22:00:00.000
2019-07-23 21:11:46.973  21:50:00.000
```

I am using the following code to create the time difference value column

```
 df3['NEW'] = ((pd.to_timedelta(df3.Time.astype(str))- 
  pd.to_timedelta(df3.order_created_time_local.dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))) /
                 np.timedelta64(1, 'm'))
```

What I am getting is below and the needed column is what I want the values to be:

```
Date                               Time      Difference      Needed
2019-08-21 21:57:28.721      21:30:00.000   -19.883333     -19.883333
2019-08-21 22:16:57.795      04:00:00.000   -1096.950000.    420.000
2019-08-21 21:00:00.00       21:30:00.000      30.000        30.000
```

because in the 24 hour clock 04:00:00.000 would be 4:00am and 22:16 would be 10:16PM, is there a way I can calculate the correct difference in minutes based on this?

**Detail** : Time represents just a time for any day. Like the closing time for a shop. No date needed just a time and difference should be just the difference in actual minutes from Time - Date ( the time in date not needing the actual date)

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, do you really have end_times which might lie before the order_created_time_local (as in your first row)? The problem here seems to be, that you have to make the `end_time_local` a full timestamp, so you need to make assumptions on the end_time local. What would they be? (e.g. if end_time_local - time part of order_created is lbetween zero and 12 hours, both timestamps are referring to the same date. If it is negative, end_time_local refers to the following day and if it is > 12 hours, it refers to the previous date). Could you add some description like that please?

Comment: One other point. What do you mean by `variance`? I guess just the time difference in some measurment (it doesn't look like the difference in minutes), because a statistical variance could never be negative, except you are calculating it for complex numbers.

Comment: @jottbe Thanks for the comment. I added some detail, Time just represents the time for any day, not related to a date. Meaning its just a time like when a shop closes everyday. Both times are in 24 hour clock from 0:00 through 24:00. Variance or difference just refers to the difference from Time minus the Time in Date field. Let me know if that helps and is better detail, thanks!

Comment: The difference should be the difference in minutes because sometimes the Time in date column can be later than the Time column ( 4:00 - 5:00) so value for difference can be negative @jottbe

Comment: Hmmm thanks for the reply. So if it is the same day, I guess the shops are partly located in a different time zone, right? There would be an easy solution for that I guess, but not if the time difference can indeed be negative. How can an automatic logic find out, when the time difference ins relly negative and when it is just negative due to different time zones.

Comment: Thanks, no the shops are same timezone, just a certain time zone of that day, so every shop is in that rows timezone @jottbe